# Shopaholic forcing slug to be unique and creates multiple pages with a number suffixes

Tags: octobercms

I'm using october and shopaholic. For example, I have a slug "pumpkins" in my category "Halloween". So, I've got URL: /hallowenn/pumpkins/ . When I creating another "pumpkins" slug, in a different category (toys), shopaholic forcing slug to pumpkins-2. Moreover - I have /toys/punkins-2/ and /toys/pumpkins/ . The last one is with the wrong additional fields and stuff.
Is it normal behavior for october+shopaholic? Is it a good idea to fix it via beforeSave/aftershave fix for the product model? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected behavior with auto-generated slugs. Sluggable fields are expected to be unique so that with just that one piece of information you would be able to fetch the correct model. You could manually set the slug field in your code, ie:

```
$category = new Category;
$category->name = 'Pumpkins';
$category->slug = 'pumkins';
$category->save(); // Slug will not be generated
```

Though, I haven't looked at the Shopaholic code, so I'm not sure if this would be safe to do. I would recommend sticking with the limitation, or using another solution to rewrite the urls, such as Apache Rewrties.

https://octobercms.com/docs/database/traits#sluggable